# Which tool for monitoring the number of outgoing mails in Postfix?

Tags: postfix, monitoring, alert

which tool (script, nagios plugin, whatever) can I use to monitor tge rate of outgoing mails on a postfix mail server? I would like that script to calculate the number of outgoing mails per minute or every ten minutes or so and alert me by e-mail if that rate exceeds a predefined number, thus detecting possible spam waves.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4003732/282601

Answer (score 2):

[Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) has two plugins, `postfix_mailstats` and `postfix_mailvolume`, which should do what you want.  It can also cope with thresholds, and if those are exceeded feed a notification through a NAGIOS server, or directly to anything else you care to plug into it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. All helped me in on way or the other. In the end, I took the one core grep line for the munin plugin and wrapped my own alert script around it.

Comment: Michael: glad we could help.  Don't forget to accept your preferred answer by clicking on the "tick" outline next to it; it drives the SF reputation system for all concerned.

Answer (score 0):

[Cacti® - The Complete RRDTool-based Graphing Solution](http://www.cacti.net/), can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [qshape](http://www.postfix.org/qshape.1.html) ; you should be able to awk sum params you want from qshape easily and send notice if needed. Periodic checks can be easily set up using cronjob.